# Commerce Server Catalog Manager SearchOptions setPaging

Tags: c#, microsoft-commerce-server

I am using this method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.commerceserver.catalog.commonsearchoptions.setpaging.aspx

as such:

```
        CatalogSearch p = catalogContext.GetCatalogSearch();
        p.CatalogNames = "**";
        p.SearchOptions = new CatalogSearchOptions();
        p.SearchOptions.SetPaging(1, 400);
        p.SearchOptions.ClassTypes = CatalogClassTypes.ProductClass;
```

Typically, I would then do `p.Search()` and get a `CatalogItemsDataSet`.  This is fine. What I can't figure out, is how do I go to the next page of results? My query will return around 7,500 results with a maximum of 500 per search call which isn't enough. Do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop or recurse your `Search` call, incrementing the `pageNumber` by your page size each time.  Your page size is 400, so the paging code in the loop might look like this `p.SearchOptions.SetPaging(lastPageNumber + 400);`  You stop when the `Search` method `out totalRecords` is less than the page size.